# PL/SQL:How to make sure a function exists?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Well, I facing "Insufficient Privileges" problem while running a PL/SQL function:

Here are the steps I followed: In my Windows command prompt I logged in as follows:

Code:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

I got the SQL> prompt over there and then I tried to grant privilige on my function "age" as follows:

Code:

```
 SQL> GRANT EXECUTE on AGE to SCOTT;
```

where, AGE is the function name and SCOTT is the user

I'm referring the following documentation:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php

I got the error ORA-0402: function body doesn't exist. How can I save my function body before issuing GRANT ?

Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure the proper grant is issued use the fully qualified `[schema].[object]` name when referring to the function. Otherwise you're relying on public synonyms pointing to the right object. The function must exist before you can grant it though it may not be in a valid state. You can't issue grants on objects that don't exist (well besides the catch all `EXECUTE ANY` grant but that's a special database role).

For example if the schema is `FOOBAR` and the function name is `AGE` then you would issue:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON foobar.age TO scott
```

Also, when using the function make sure that either:

1. There is a public synonym pointing to the function *and* no local synonym exists that hides the public synonym
2. or .. there is a local synonym for the function (eg `SCOTT` has a local synonym pointing to `FOOBAR.AGE`)
3. or ... you refer to the function by its fully qualified name (eg call it via `FOOBAR.AGE()`

To check if the function itself is valid you can query `ALL_OBJECTS` and check the `STATUS` column:

```
SELECT status
FROM all_objects
WHERE owner = 'FOOBAR'
  AND object_type = 'FUNCTION'
  AND object_name = 'AGE'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

I'm still wondering how can I make sure that a function must exist before issuing grant command? I mean we are not saving the function body anywhere but running the function by simply writing it on SQL Plus or creating a ".sql" file and then executing it from SQL Plus command.

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Thanks !

Comment: The grant command will fail if the function does not exist so you can test for that failure (sql*plus will exit with an error). If you want to programmatically do something different if it doesn't exist then you could put that `all_objects` status check in a PL/SQL block and issue the grant dynamically if and only if the function exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Yes, the grant command did fail as mentioned in my question but I'm wondering , why despite getting that error when I ran the function in SQL plus command, I got the message " Function Created" message? Could you please throw some light on this issue?

Comment: Oracle allows you to define functions/procedures/packages that reference objects you do not have the privileges to use. A similar situation happens if you create a function that references another function (in a different schema), then the grant for that other function is revoked (or the object is dropped). Your new function will be in a invalid state so you cannot execute it but it will still exist. If you try to compile it you'll get an error similar to yours above. To test whether your function is valid you can also try to compile it via `ALTER FUNCTION foobar COMPILE`.